# How can I backup and restore all installed fonts?

Tags: backup, fonts

I am going to re-install my system. But before I do that, I would like to prepare everything well. One thing which is missing is making a backup of all fonts I have installed. I remember that I installed some fonts manually by downloading the font file.

Is it possible to get all fonts I have currently installed on my system? How would I install them later again? (I prefer console-only solutions.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standards fonts directories are: /usr/share/fonts, /usr/local/share/fonts, and ~/.fonts.
You backup those directories, then when you've restored the contents run:

```
sudo fc-cache -f -v
```

and your fonts will be available to your system

[edit] you can also use **fc-list** to list all installed font before the backup

Answer (score 2):

Custom fonts are usually in :

```
/usr/local/share/fonts
/usr/share/fonts
~/.local/share/fonts
~/.fonts
```

To back them up copy the folder to your backup media.

Example :

```
cp /usr/local/share/fonts/ /media/backupdevice/
```

---